# How to Convert python list into nested dictionaries in pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

I am new to python and trying to convert my input list which is `["a", "b", "c"]` into nested dictionaries like `{"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}`

Comment: Yes, with recursion for instance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes it's possible

Comment: Yes, this can be done. With `functools.reduce` it can even be done in one line.

Comment: @Heike please give me one line solution.

Comment: One-liner, if you don't count that you need to `from functools import reduce`: `reduce(lambda y,x : {x: y}, reversed(my_list), {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not use this in production, but it was fun...

```
def make_dict_from_list(li):
    temp = output = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(li, 1):
        if i != len(li):
            temp[e] = {}
            temp = temp[e]
        else:
            temp[e] = []
    return output

print(make_dict_from_list(['a']))
print(make_dict_from_list(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Outputs

```
{'a': []}
{'a': {'b': {'c': []}}}
```

Comment: will you tell me why ?

Comment: @MUsmanWahab Because it's not very clear what it's doing and it's abusing some scoping "features" of Python. You should take a go at coming up with a recursive solution